# Conectar ao Banco de Dados em Azure Functions (Javascript)

Tags: postgresql, microsoft-azure, microsoft

tudo bem?

Tenho enfrentado um problema constante, e não sei mais o que tentar para resolve-lo.

Criei uma Azure Function e preciso consultar alguns dados no banco de dados, a fim de retorna-los como resposta da função.

Criei um Banco de Dados PostgreSQL no Azure, adicionei o IP no firewall, adicionando o IP da minha máquina e criei tabelas, e todo o restante.

Porém, ao tentar conectar ao banco de dados, dentro da Azure Function, simplesmente não se retorna nada, nem se conecta.

O que fazer diante disso?

Desde já, obrigado!

Meu código:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    const pg = require('pg');

    // Connect to DB with Long String in App Settings

    const client = new pg.Client(GetEnvironmentVariable("AzurePGDB"));
    client.connect();
    const query = 'select * from table';

    client.query(query, (err, res) => {
        context.res = {
           body: res
        }
    });

   context.done();
};

function GetEnvironmentVariable(name) {
    return name + ": " + process.env[name];
}
```